# soporte para bases de datos Sybase

Tags: base-de-datos, sybase

Alguien podría ayudarme indicándome en que fecha SyBase 12 dejo de tener soporte y cual es la fecha de vencimiento para el soporte de SyBase 15? estoy buscando esta información en la web pero no la consigo.

Saludos.

Comment: Realmente no encontré algo oficial. Sólo este link: http://sybase-architect.blogspot.com/2019/02/sybase-ase-sap-ase-eol-source-sap-pam.html con estos datos: SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7 Dec 31 2020
SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5 Mar 31 2015 (not in SAP PAM)
SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.0.x Mar 31 2015 (not in SAP PAM)

Comment: Esto parece una pregunta mas para el soporte técnico o la propia documentación que para la comunidad, lee [ask]

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte, pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna documentación oficial